# Catenate different operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I am trying to implement a class that supports concatenation with different operators:

```
class MyClass {
public:

template<typename T>
MyClass &operator<<(const T& val ) {
  //do something with val
  return *this;
}

template<typename T>
MyClass &operator=(const T& val) {
  //do something with val
  return *this;
} 

};

int main() {
  MyClass a;
  a << "hallo" = 3 << "huuh"; //compiler will complain about 
}
```

Do i miss something here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the expression

```
a << "hallo" = 3 << "huuh";
```

is evaluated as

```
(a << "hallo") = (3 << "huuh");
```

and your compiler is complaining about the lack of a valid `operator<<(int, const char[5])`.

You will need to use brackets to change the precedence:

```
(a << "hallo" = 3) << "huuh";
```

That said, it is extremely hard to understand what is going on here, operators should be used to make things clearer, not harder to read.